# Finding the shortest, second shortest, second longest and longest word in String using only certain JAVA APIs

Tags: java

This code counts lengths of `shortest`, `second shortest`, `second longest` and `longest` words used in `String`. The program is using `trim`, `substring` and `indexOf` from String API. Can this be done without using those APIs. 
I have been trying to get it work using only `.length()` `equals` and `.charAt()`but I can't figure out how it can be done.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    public class wordlength {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello how are you doing";
        String trim=str.trim()+" ";
        String longest= trim.substring(0,trim.indexOf(' '));
        String seclong = trim.substring(0,trim.indexOf(' '));
        String shortest = trim.substring(0,trim.indexOf(' '));
        String secshort = trim.substring(0,trim.indexOf(' '));
        int length=trim.length();
        String temp="";

        for(int i=trim.indexOf(' ')+1;i<length;i++){
        char ch=trim.charAt(i);

            if(ch!=' ')
            temp=temp+ch;
                else{
                    if(temp.length()>longest.length()){
                        seclong=longest;
                        longest=temp;
                    }
                    else if(temp.length()>seclong.length()){
                        seclong=temp;
                    }
                    temp=" ";
                }
            }

        for(int i=trim.indexOf(' ')+1;i<length;i++){
        char ch=trim.charAt(i);

            if(ch!=' ')
            temp=temp+ch;
                else{
                    if(temp.length()<shortest.length()){
                        secshort=shortest;
                        shortest=temp;
                    }
                    else if(temp.length()<secshort.length()){
                        secshort=temp;
                    }
                    temp=" ";
                }
            }
            String space = " ";
            int shortestint = (shortest.replaceAll(space, "").length());
            int secshortint = (secshort.replaceAll(space, "").length());
            int longestint = (longest.replaceAll(space, "").length());
            int seclongint = (seclong.replaceAll(space, "").length());

            System.out.println("- The length of the shortest part is "+ shortestint + ".");
            System.out.println("- The length of the second shortest part is "+ secshortint + ".");
            System.out.println("- The length of the second longest part is "+seclongint + ".");
            System.out.println("- The length of the longest part is "+longestint + ".");

        }
    }
```

> ```
> > The output =
> > - The length of the shortest part is 3.
> > - The length of the second shortest part is 3.
> > - The length of the second longest part is 5.
> > - The length of the longest part is 5.
> ```

Comment: Please fix code indentation in order to get help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way of doing the same thing, with no `substring`, `trim` or `indexOf`. It does require arrays though. Also, I'm using `String.split`, but you can substitute it for a loop on the string's characters.

The idea is this - we'll split the string into words, and store the length of each word in an array. We'll later sort that array of lengths:

```
String str = "Hello how are you doing";
String[] words = str.split(" ");
int [] wordLengths = new int[words.length];

for (int i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
    wordLengths[i] = words[i].length();
}

Arrays.sort(wordLengths);

System.out.println("- The length of the shortest part is " + wordLengths[0] + ".");
System.out.println("- The length of the second shortest part is " +  wordLengths[1] + ".");
System.out.println("- The length of the second longest part is " +  wordLengths[wordLengths.length-2] + ".");
System.out.println("- The length of the longest part is " +  wordLengths[wordLengths.length-1] + ".");
```

Output:

```
- The length of the shortest part is 3.
- The length of the second shortest part is 3.
- The length of the second longest part is 5.
- The length of the longest part is 5.
```